# Creating data views for file types other than XML and JSON in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, kml, cakephp-2.4

How can I export data from a CakePHP 2.4 app as KML, not just XML and JSON?

This is what I've been trying:

1: I created a simple controller action, `download`, to find all data in my model:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
```

2: I addeded the file type in `routes.php`:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml', 'kml', 'csv');
```

3: I created a folder for my data view file type:

```
/app/View/Post/kml
```

4: I created a view, `download.ctp`, which manually echos out the XML tags for the KML file.

Now comes the problem: When I place this view file under `/app/View/Post/xml`, visiting /posts/download.xml creates a valid KML document I can open in Google Earth, albeit with an .XML extension. When I place the file under `/app/View/Post/kml`, and visit /posts/download.kml, it throws an error: **View file "/home/public/app/View/Themed/Cakestrap/Posts/download.ctp" is missing.**

I tried copying my view to the above location, but that just echos the XML into my standard layout. What's the proper way to create data views for filetypes other than XML and JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saddly KML does not have a mime type recognized in servers [vide Google](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server). So when you add it to `Router::ParseExtensions(...)` Cake can't see that extension and won't try to access your `download.ctp` inside kml folder.

You have two alternatives to setup this to work:

- Change server settings in order to it recognize the extension [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server).
- Try to call render manually like this:

  ```
  <?php
  $this->response->type("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
  $this->render('kml/download.ctp', 'xml');
  ```

Comment: The approach  to call render manually works fine, but the resulting file to be downloaded gets a text/html content type/ I ended up putting a <?php exit; ?> command at the end of the kml default.cto layout to stop any additional processing from CakePHP. After that,  browsers understand that the attachment is a .kml file and use GoogleEarth to open it.

Comment: Good that it worked for you. If you could mark my solution as accepted I would be honored (first one). And about the header you can change it if you need by doing the following before rendering:

    $this->response->type("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");


I'll update my answer for sake of completeness.

Comment: Pedro,  you are 100% correct. The correct way is to set the response header and then everything works ok. The <?php exit; I suggested may do the job, but it is certainly the wrong way to do it :)